# When I'm going through azure iot hub tutorial, creating end with error partition count 4 - why?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

Depending on tutorial at [microsoft website for IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-cli) if you type in second step:

```
az iot hub create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name {YourIoTHubName}
```

**in your cli, error comes up:** *Invalid PartitionCount 4 - value must be between 2 and 2. If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: ******-f9a8-4b36-a566-******, timestamp: 2019-06-04 14:32:30Z, errorcode: IH400016.*

See my answer below for fixing ;)

Answer (score 9):

This error comes up when you're in a free tier and azure wants to use default values for remaining settings, in this case like **partition-count** (default is 4)

Use instead:

```
az iot hub create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name {YourIoTHubName}  --partition-count 2
```

In Free Tier you only can use 2 partions. It'll work then!